# Google Apps Script clear data from entire sheet before another function

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function running in Google Apps Script, that imports data from a csv file. It is working fine, but I want it to clear the data first in the specific sheet. How do I get this job done? Two separate functions do work, but I want it to clear the data before it imports the csv, within the same function.

How do I implement it in the function below?

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var url = 'https://urlofimport.csv';
  var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(text);

  var gid = "0";  // Please set your sheet ID (gid).
  var sheet = ss.getSheets().filter(s => s.getSheetId() == gid);
  if (sheet.length == 1) {
    sheet[0].getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  }
}
```

I already tried 2 separate functions, but I want it in the same function to be running.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following lines to your `if` statement:

```
sheet[0].getRange(1, 1, sheet[0].getLastRow(), sheet[0].getLastColumn()).clearContent();
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

This should get clear all the contents on the desired sheet.  I added in `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` just to be on the safe side since I had no CSV file to test with.  This should ensure that clearing of the contents is finished before the CSV file is imported.  However, you may find that it is unnecessary.

The final code would look like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var url = 'https://urlofimport.csv';
  var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(text);

  var gid = "0";  // Please set your sheet ID (gid).
  var sheet = ss.getSheets().filter(s => s.getSheetId() == gid);
  if (sheet.length == 1) {
    sheet[0].getRange(1, 1, sheet[0].getLastRow(), sheet[0].getLastColumn()).clearContent();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    sheet[0].getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you Codedabbler! :)